# Google Gmail scopes how to verify in cloud plartform?

Tags: gmail-api

I have create gmail like email app and i need to used for google gmail api and set all needed scopes into cloud plartform but issue is which type of video url to add in verify restricted scopes.

```
 Please tell me which types video upload youtube and used as url add in cloud plartform outh verification.
```

Comment: I don't understand. How does a video url relate to the gmail api? Are you trying to send or receive a video with an email or are you just using the wrong word?

Comment: You need to create a screen recording of your app; one which shows you authorising the app to run as you (the auth window which comes up on install) and then a demonstration of how your app uses the restricted scopes. For example: if your app sends an email on your behalf, show in the video how it is done. Also make sure that the full URL is viewable in the video for the OAuth consent screen pop-up. Upload the video to YouTube as an unlisted video and share the URL in the input box provided.